# Three.js -- webkitSpeechRecognition not working after deviceorientation event

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, device-orientation, webspeech-api

In my JS code, i have the following listener:

```
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', setOrientationControls, true);

    ...
    function setOrientationControls(e) {

      if (!e.alpha) {
        return;
      }

      controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(camera, true);
      controls.connect();
      controls.update();

      //disable further -- else gives jitter effect
      window.removeEventListener('deviceorientation', setOrientationControls, true);
    }
```

Separately i have the following code to recognize speech using the HTML5 webspeech API:

```
    function initSpeech(){
      recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
      recognition.continuous = true;
      recognition.onresult = function(event) {
       for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++) {
              if (event.results[i].isFinal) {

                var text = event.results[i][0].transcript;
                // ... do something with text
               }
        }
       }
       recognition.start();
    }
```

The speech recognition works on initialization, however, once the device orientation is changed, speech recognition no longer works.

Is there a solution to make it work post device orientation, without having to initialize the speech recognition all over (it asks for browser audio-permission each time you initialize it).